Spring JmsTransactionManager TransactionStatus null
I am using Spring JmsTransactionManager but sometimes getting TransactionStatus as null. Eventhough I added retry logic its same. How can make sure I always get active Transaction in case of status is null? Is it because of using CachingConnectionFactory with jmstransaction manager where caching the connections ? May be sometime underlying MQ host not available?
Exception:
Could not create JMS transaction

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus.isCompleted()" because "status" is null
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionMan
ager.java:859)





 @EnableJms
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class ConnectionConfig {
    
        @Qualifier("gatewayConnectionFactory")
        public MQConnectionFactory gatewayConnectionFactory() {
            MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
            try {
                mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(hostname);
                mqConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
                mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(channelname);
                mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception while connecting to QManager Gateway - " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return mqConnectionFactory;
        }
        
        @Bean(name = "gatewayCachingConnectionFactory")
        public CachingConnectionFactory gatewayCachingConnectionFactory() {
            CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            factory.setSessionCacheSize(50);
            factory.setTargetConnectionFactory(gatewayConnectionFactory());
            return factory;
        }
        
    
        @Bean("jmsTemplate")
        public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
            JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(gatewayCachingConnectionFactory());
            jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
            return jmsTemplate;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
            JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
            jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(gatewayCachingConnectionFactory());
            return jmsTransactionManager;
        }
        
    }
    
    @Component
    public class MessageDeliver {
        
        
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("jmsTemplate")
        private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
        
        
        @Autowired
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager;
        
         public void publishMessages(String payload, MQQueue destinationQueue) throws Exception {
            
              TransactionStatus status = null;
              try {
                   status =  jmsTransactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW));
                    jmsTemplate.send(destinationQueue, session -> {
                        TextMessage txtMessage = session.createTextMessage();
                        txtMessage.setText((String)payload);
                        return txtMessage;
                    
                    });
                }
                jmsTransactionManager.commit(status);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    log.error("Exception occured while delivering the message, so rollbaking the transaction");
                    jmsTransactionManager.rollback(status);
                } catch (Exception rollbackException) {
                    log.error("Exception occurred while rolling back the transaction", rollbackException);
                    
                }
           }
          
        }   
    }   

